# Foundation's Abide validation and tabs

Tags: javascript, validation, zurb-foundation, foundation-abide

[Abide](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html) from version 5.5.2 does not validate hidden fields. However, that also means that the validation does not work for fields in inactive tabs.

Sample code could be:

```html
<form data-abide>
    <ul class="tabs" data-tab>
      <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel1">Tab Name</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab Email</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-content">
      <div class="content active" id="panel1">
          <div class="name-field">
            <label>Your name <small>required</small>
              <input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
            </label>
            <small class="error">Name is required and must be a string.</small>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="panel2">
          <div class="email-field">
            <label>Email <small>required</small>
              <input type="email" required>
            </label>
            <small class="error">An email address is required.</small>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Live here: http://jsfiddle.net/1ukfgwqt/ (don't click the second tab before clicking Submit).

Is there a way, other than downgrading to 5.5.1 or manually editing Foundation's JS files, to reenable validation for hidden fields or fix validation for inactive tabs (until the [issue I reported](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6625) is fixed)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
my solution was to have a callback on the tabs and reflows abide like this :

```
    $(document).foundation({
        tab: {
            callback: function (tab) {
                $(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try it on the fiddle I prepared? It doesn't make any difference…